# Magento get customer by Tax/VAT number field

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am looking to something similar to this one (thats works with email), But instead of get the customer by email, i want to get him by the  Tax/VAT number.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($website->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
```

I found this example but  its doesn't work.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('taxvat',  $ss_5_last)->load();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the attribute *taxvat* contains unique values, your approach was almost right. But the result of your second try returns a collection. I think you need a customer object, so try this one:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('taxvat',  $ss_5_last)
            ->getFirstItem();
```

This returns a customer object you can work with. Caution: If taxvat does NOT contain unique values, this method could return the wrong customer, because it always returns the first item of a collection with more than one item.